# Understanding equation of a line.

Tags: geometry

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 87)

> Let $a, b$ be numbers. The graph of the equation
> $$
> y=ax+b \tag{1}
> $$
> is also a straight line, which is parallel to the graph of the equation
> $$
> y=ax \tag{2}
> $$

> To convince ourselves of this, we observe the following. Let $y' = y - b$.
> The equation
> $$
> y'=ax \tag{3}
> $$
> is of the type just discussed.

> If we have a point $(x, y')$ on the graph of (3), then we get a point $(x, y' + b)$ on the graph of (1), simply by adding b to the second coordinate. This means that the graph of the equation $y=ax+b$ is the straight line parallel to the line determined by the equation $y = ax$, and passing through the point $(0, b)$.

Does someone understand what's the concept behind this explanation ? What's the author trying to convey when he adds $b$ to the second coordinate ?

EDIT: I would like to also know, if possible, what's the meaning of "If we have a point $(x, y')$ on the graph of (3), then we get a point $(x, y' + b)$".

Comment: It looks like they are just trying to convey that every point in the first line is just the second line shifted up by $b$ units and so still parallel to the second line.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterForeman. In the explanation, I see the use of $y'$. It then appears as the second coordinate in $(x,y'+b)$. Do you know where does come from ? I cannot seem to follow that reasoning. And, the connection between (1), (2) and (3).

Comment: Notice that you wrote $y' = y -b$ so that $y' + b = y$ just by moving $b$ to the left side. So the coordinate $(x, y'+b) = (x,y)$ just by substituting $y' + b = y$.

Comment: Oh, I understand a little more, now. Thank you, @AsAnExerciseProve.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a constant such as $b$ has the effect of translating the graph vertically (whatever the function), because every point moves up by amount $b$.

The equation $y=ax$ is the equation of a line through the origin $(0,0)$, with a some slope.

Adding $b$ yields the equation of *any* line, i.e. with some slope and through some point, namely $(0,b)$.

Comment: I see what you explain. Thank you, @Yves Daoust.  However, I am lost in the chain of reasonings the author does. For example, where does the point $y' = y - b$ come from ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to reduce confusion I will change equation (1) to $\hat{y} = ax + b$. The author wants to relate this function to $y=ax$. To do so notice that,
\begin{align}
\hat{y} &= ax + b \\
\hat{y} -b &= ax
\end{align}
This equation has the same form as $y=ax$ if the left side is $y$. So if we define a new variable $y'$ where $\hat{y}-b = y'$ then we get, $y' = ax$. Therefore, $y'$ and $y$ both describe the same line, i.e., $y'= ax$ and $y = ax$. This means that we can relate $\hat{y}$ with $y$,
\begin{align}\hat{y} -b &= y' \quad (\text{original definition})\\
\hat{y} &= y'+b \quad (*) \\
\hat{y} -b &= y \quad (\text{because } y=y') \\
\hat{y} &= y+b \quad (**)
\end{align}
So $\hat{y}$ is the line $y$ plus $b$. The effect of adding $b$ is that the whole line gets translated vertically $b$ units. If we have the point $(x,y')$ we can get the point $(x,\hat{y})$ by using $(*)$ above, i.e., $(x,\hat{y}) = (x, y'+b)$.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand every operation you are doing but still cannot fully understand the concept behind the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to say: if we have a  point $(x',y')$ because $x$ axis itself has displaced parallelly so that $ y'= y-b$  as shown,  to reduce confusion.

After subtracting $b,$ the straight line graph of same slope $a$ should pass through new origin $O'$ as shown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Will digest it a little bit to see if I understand the concept.